# How to import a sheet without windows screen updating?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to import a sheet from another book

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Workbooks.Open fileName:=ThisWorkbook.path & "\temp01.xlsx"
Workbooks("temp01.xlsx").Sheets.Copy before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("adm")
Workbooks("temp01.xlsx").Close False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

But in windows taskbar is visible that the book si opened and, after a few seconds - closed.
Is there a way to import a sheet without opening the target book, or opening it without win taskbar updating ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this line to the start of your code.

```
Application.Visible = False
```

and this list to end of your code

```
Application.Visible = True
```

It will hide the Excel application on your taskbar while your code is running.

Comment: Robert, in this case the whole Excel window becomes hiden and visible again. And plus - win taskbar also changes. I need to import a sheet silently, without flickering anything on the screen.

Comment: Have a look at this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680061/how-can-i-stop-excel-workbook-flicker-on-automation-open