# Hide a opened workbook before it is visible to user

Tags: vba, excel

I hook into the on workbook open event like this:

```
Private WithEvents App As Application ' For handling events

' Event handler for when THIS workbook is opened.
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set App = Application ' Set App variable so we can add event handlers
    App.EnableEvents = True ' Set raise events = true.
End Sub

' Event handler to handle the event when a new workbook is open (ie. when Raven Viewer exports to a new workbook in excel
Private Sub App_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    Wb.Windows(1).Visible = False
End Sub
```

which hides any workbooks that are opened whilst this spreadsheet is open...but for a brief second, they are visible to the user. Is there any way I can prevent this?

I am trying to prevent the current open workbook from loosing any focus.

The workbook is not opened with VBA.

Thanks.

Comment: `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` inside `App_WorkbookOpen` might do it.

Comment: @JacobYoung this was my first port of call, didn't work. I understand this is probably going to require a megahack if I do get it to work.

Comment: You may find this link useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680061/how-can-i-stop-excel-workbook-flicker-on-automation-open/

Answer (score 0):

Using  `App_WindowActivate` seems to work better for me, but I'm not positive:

```
Private Sub App_WindowActivate(ByVal Wb As Workbook, ByVal Wn As Window)
If Not Wn Is ThisWorkbook.Windows(1) Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Wn.Visible = False
    ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: No luck, exactly the same issue im afraid. Thanks